# Django ModelForm is_valid() error types

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a `EmailField(primary_key=True)`.  I'm using a `ModelForm` to render a form to a user and on the post back I am calling `form.is_valid()`.

I am seeing two types of errors on this field.  One is a unique value constraint on the primary key (this email address already exists).  The other is an invalid email address error.

I would like to respond differently to each error.  Is there an easy way to identify that validation failure was due to an actual input format error vs a unique constraint?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured out how to achieve what I wanted.  My goal was to avoid the unique constraint so that I could silently ignore the form submission and succeed (from the user perspective, since their submission was a noop) in the case of a duplicate email address being submitted.

First override the `validate_unique` method on my `ModelForm` definition.

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from apps.announcer.models import Subscriber

class SubscribeForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Subscriber
        exclude = ('created',)

    def validate_unique(self):
        pass
```

Because the `validate_unique` method has been converted to a noop the view will have to perform whatever validation it needs.  So instead of calling `form.save()` call `entity = form.save(commit=False)`.  Perform the needed validation on entity and if needed call `entity.save()`.

Answer (score 1):

Could you check for a pre-existing key first, then call `is_valid()`?

Comment: is there a way to do is_valid without performing the unique constraint validation?

Comment: IIRC, the unique constraint is performed by the database, whenever you hit the database, so probably not.